# dlib RuntimeError with floating points in my xml

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, runtime-error, dlib

I have an problem with dlib that i created my test data and when i try to create my model the runtime error occurs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train_shape_predictor.py", line 34, in <module>
dlib.train_shape_predictor(training_xml_path, "predictor.dat", options)
RuntimeError: Error on line 5: string cast error: invalid string = '11.29'
```

the problem is that i have floating points in my xml filei Couldn't I use xml file with floating points?